# SAS - Access SAS dataset from separate server

Tags: sas

Scenario:

- I run SAS programs from Sasfusion server abc123.
- I run regular SAS programs with proc contents, proc prints, proc exports, etc with no issue.

I was just requested to access a SAS dataset in location on a separate server zyx123 (not sure if it is Sasfusion or not)

I thought this would be something simple like putting in a libname statement.

```
libname z '\path to the folder\' server=zyx123;

proc contents data = z.requesteddataset;
run;
```

Is it possible to even do the above?

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Libref TEST is not assigned.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
ERROR 23-7: Invalid value for the SERVER option.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LIBNAME` option `SERVER=` is used to access to data sets on a machine with SAS/SHARE licensed running a SAS session in which `Proc SERVER` is executing.

See the [SAS/SHARE User's Guide, LIBNAME](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=shrref&docsetTarget=n03d753hzvcmg8n1a6suvnadpfo5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) documentation:

> **LIBNAME Statement**
>   In a client session, associates a libref (a shortcut name) with a SAS library that is located on the server for client access. In a server session, predefines a server library that clients are permitted to access.
>   …
>
> **SERVER=**<server-node.>**server-name | __port-number**
>   specifies the location and identity of the SAS/SHARE server session that administers the SAS library.

You should request additional information about the remote server from you network / SAS administrator.

Not sure about your specific ERROR messages logged -- the log for an unsuccessful libname (on my machine) looks like:

```
12   libname foo 'c:\temp' server=#######.######;
ERROR: Attempt to connect to server #######.###### failed.
ERROR: A communication subsystem partner link setup request failure has occurred.
ERROR: The connection was refused.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```